# Read mail (IMAP) but only show messages from certain email address

Tags: objective-c, ios, email, get, imap

Can I retrieve emails using IMAP server details from a UITextField and show them in a UITableView but only show emails which come from a certain email address (e.g. example@example.com)?

Thanks,

James

Comment: This is a broad, multi-step problem; what have you done so far?

Comment: I have set up an SMS style view where you can send messages using SMTP but now, I need it to receive messages - but only ones which are from a certain email address. I already have a UITableView set up. All I need is some code to retrieve and filter the emails...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMTP is for sending Mails, not receiving them. If you want to try IMAP for receiving check  [MailCore](http://www.mronge.com/m/MailCore/API/), it might help some hassle implementing IMAP.

Comment: thanks, but I can't see anything which would be of any use to me there :S

Comment: There should be some kind of server that receives the mail you expect to retrieve. And that server should allow access by the means of IMAP or POP. To access the server using IMAP MailCore will help.

Comment: Yes but then how can I display the certain emails in the UITableView? :S